# How to develop nice-looking, visually modern applications in QT?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

I'm wondering how to develop visually modern, with attractive GUI applications in QT. When I run QT Creator and start new project, the GUI looks very basic and "pure", just like simple win32 apps. But look for example at Allegorithmic Substance Designer 2, where GUI looks somehow similar to WPF. There are many other applications with nice-looking GUI. So, the question is: how to do this? Is there any extension/library to QT, which provide richer GUI experience? Or it must be developed from scratch? Thanks for replies in advance.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/qtbynokia/how-to-make-your-qt-app-look-native may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as Nano's answer, I think it would be worth your while to search around for any Qt stylesheets others have made.

For example, [this one](http://www.mimec.org/articles/qt/wmstyle) that mimics Microsoft Office.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be very many of them available.

I found these useful links, some of whose links may give some ideas:

- [Qt Stylesheet Snippet Repository](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=21219)

Another idea might be to search for example qml files in [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch). This [search for .qml](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=file%3a%5C.qml&type=cs) files has plenty of hits. Before using any of them, you would obviously need to check its license.

Comment: Wmstyle,i tried the latest version of it with the latest version of qt sdk and has bugs.

Comment: Have you tried any of the many that are listed on the Qt Stylesheet Snippet Repository?

Comment: I tried wmstyle many weeks ago and did not work because of a bug.I tried what i could to fix it but kept re-emerging and i left the style altogether and used qt cleanlooks style.I am studying css currently so i can't use any in the repo.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Nokia's [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)? If you're looking for something "similar" to WPF I assume you're referring to its declarative nature, [QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html) being XAML's counterpart in such regard.